# React js rerender of large number of components in a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very large dynamic form that is rendered based on data gathered through AJAX.

There is a form containing a table. The table contains a header and then a series of rows (as determined by the state data). Each row then has a series of cells (also determined by the state data). Each of those cells contain a checkbox.

My question is about where to maintain the state of the large number of checkboxes. Initially my approach was to make the checkboxes controlled components with each cell maintaining the state of its checkbox.

I also tried implementing the state of the selection boxes as state on the parent form component itself.

The problem with the former approach is that when I come to submit the form, I don't have the state at the form level as it's buried down in the cell descendants. Can I get this state somehow? `findDomNode` seems to be current component only, not cascading. Also, the header cells have checkboxes that are checked whenever all the rows in the column are checked, this solution doesn't enable me to have the information to update that.

The problem with the latter approach is that when I make a change to one checkbox, the state change causes the form component to be re-rendered, which in turn causes the whole table to be re-rendered (or at least to have it's render methods called). This is very time consuming and for a big table (often it can be 100x50) takes a very unfriendly amount of time to rerender.

At the end of the day, the ramifications of checking a checkbox should be very small. The checkbox itself should update, and the column header may need to be updated to be checked/unchecked if the column's fully-selected state has changed. That's it.

I've stripped out a lot of the code, but this is basically what I am working with. It may be helpful to know that the cell checkboxes in the table are keeping track of which tags should be applied to images. The table header cells keep track of which tokens (text extracted from the image name) are mapped to which tags. When this changes, that column would have to be rerendered (another problem I haven't tackled yet which I suspect will again be difficult without fully rerendering everything).

```
var AutoTagForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: {
        tags: [],
        images: {},
        tokens: [],
        tokenTagMap: {}
      }
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      type: "POST",
      data: { imageIds: this.props.images },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  onSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Submit the updates to the server
  },

  cellCheckedChange: function(image, tag) {
    // If the image has the tag, add it. Otherwise remove it

    var tagIndex = image.checkedTags.indexOf(tag)

    // TODO Perhaps it is safer to find the image object in this.state.data?
    if (tagIndex === -1) {
      image.checkedTags.push(tag);
    } else {
      image.checkedTags.splice(tagIndex, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data
    })

  },

  render: function() {
    var images = this.state.data.images;
    var tokenTagMap = this.state.data.tokenTagMap;
    var cellCheckedChange = this.cellCheckedChange;

    var rowNodes = Object.keys(images).map(function(key){
      if (images.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var image = images[key];

        return (
          <AutoTagImageRow key={image.id}
                           image={image}
                           tokenTagMap={tokenTagMap}
                           cellCheckedChange={cellCheckedChange} />
        );
      }
    });

    return (
      <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} id="updateAllForm" className={'autotagForm'}>
        <div>
          <input type="submit"
                 value="Apply" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <AutoTagHeaderRow tags={this.state.data.tags}
                                tokens={this.state.data.tokens}
                                tokenTagMap={this.state.data.tokenTagMap} />
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {rowNodes}
            </tbody>

          </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
  }
});


var AutoTagImageRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var image = this.props.image;
    var tokenTagMap = this.props.tokenTagMap;
    var cellCheckedChange = this.props.cellCheckedChange;

    var cellNodes = Object.keys(tokenTagMap).map(function(token){
      if (tokenTagMap.hasOwnProperty(token)) {
        return (
          <AutoTagImageRowCell image={image}
                               token={token}
                               tokenTagMap={tokenTagMap}
                               cellCheckedChange={cellCheckedChange} />
        );
      }
    });

    return (
      <tr>
        {cellNodes}
        <td>{image.clientPath}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});


var AutoTagImageRowCell = React.createClass({

  isTagged: function() {
    var image = this.props.image;
    var token = this.props.token;
    var tokenTagMap = this.props.tokenTagMap;
    var tag = tokenTagMap[token];

    return (image.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1);
  },

  isChecked: function() {
    var image = this.props.image;
    var token = this.props.token;
    var tokenTagMap = this.props.tokenTagMap;
    var tag = tokenTagMap[token];

    return (image.checkedTags.indexOf(tag) !== -1);
  },

  handleCheckedChange: function() {
    var image = this.props.image;
    var token = this.props.token;
    var tokenTagMap = this.props.tokenTagMap;
    var tag = tokenTagMap[token];

    this.props.cellCheckedChange(image, tag);
  },

  render: function() {

    var className = '';
    if (this.isTagged()) {
      className = 'success';
    }

    return (
      <td className={className}>
        <input type="checkbox"
               checked={this.isChecked()}
               onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} />
      </td>
    );
  }
});
```

I am new to React and possibly making some bad design decisions! This is very different to how I was doing things before by using simple javascript and I'm keen to follow the React philosophy, but I feel like it has gone wrong for me almost immediately as this is the first thing I've tried to do past the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After some additional research I have found a pretty good solution to this problem.

The key is to be able to tell which components need rerendering. This was something I had previously considered, but the comparisons required on my state to determine if an image row would need to be rerendered were nearly as intensive as the rerendering itself.

Enter [Immutable.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js). I turned my javascript objects into immutable maps and my arrays into immutable sets. Like this:

```
    for (var key in data.images) {
      // data.images[key] = Immutable.fromJS(data.images[key]);

      data.images[key] = Immutable.fromJS(
        data.images[key], function (key, value) {
          var isIndexed = Immutable.Iterable.isIndexed(value);
          return isIndexed ? value.toSet() : value.toMap();
        }
      );
    }
```

I didn't transform the whole of `data` just yet as there are other bits of data in there that are not yet updated to be using immutable, but that would be possible.

Then when I handle an onChange from one of my checkboxes I implement it at the form-level like so:

```
  cellCheckedChange: function(imageId, tagId) {
    var images = this.state.data.images;
    var image = images[imageId];

    // If the image has the tag, add it. Otherwise remove it
    var checked = image.hasIn(['checkedTags', tagId]);

    images[imageId] = image.update('checkedTags', function(value) {
      return checked ? value.delete(tagId): value.add(tagId);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data
    });

  },
```

So an update to an immutable object causes a new object to be created. That will have an upward cascading effect on the immutable state structure because any change to a child necessitates a new parent. Any state that is not updated either directly or through this upward cascade is still the same objects though, which is important because you can reason about those independently.

Finally, I updated my image row component to only update if the image was a new object (which it will be if the image or any descendant has updated):

```
var AutoTagImageRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    ...
  },
  // Only update an image row that has had a modified state
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.image !== this.props.image;
  }
  ...
});
```

So when an update occurs, a little bit more work occurs manipulating the javascript state, but in return, I can reason about what has and has not changed very easily!

As I mentioned above, any parts of the nested hierarchy of immutable objects that are not replaced are the same objects, thus it is possible to compare those to the children of the old structure to see if they have been updated with the result that they have not. Here is a self contained example.

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');

var input = {
  '1': 'aaa',
  '2': [1,2,3,4]
};

var x = Immutable.fromJS(
  input, function (key, value) {
    var isIndexed = Immutable.Iterable.isIndexed(value);
    return isIndexed ? value.toSet() : value.toMap();
  }
);

// Get another reference to x
var y = x;

// Update the array stored in '2'
x = x.update('2', function(v) {
    return v.add(7);
});

// object '1' remains the same JS object
console.log(x.get('1') === y.get('1')); //True

// object '2' is a new JS object
console.log(x.get('2') === y.get('2')); //False

// Overall 'x' is a new JS object
console.log(x === y); //False
```